# .htaccess issue with Laravel 4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble getting my pretty URLs to work in a new Laravel 4 no OS X.

In addition to the default route, I've set up a route at `/hello`.

If I navigate here it works: `http://localhost/~myuser/mytest/public/`

If I navigate here it works: `http://localhost/~myuser/mytest/public/index.php?hello`

If I navigate here it does **not** work: `http://localhost/~myuser/mytest/public/hello`

This is what I have in my .htaccess file in my public folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing to get the pretty URLs working?

Comment: Where is the `.htaccess` file stored?

Comment: @MikeAnthony `http://localhost/~myuser/mytest/public/` aka `/Users/myuser/Sites/mytest/public`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteBase /~myuser/mytest/public/
```

This should go just below `RewriteEngine On`.

Also, in `/app/config/app.php` make sure that you've set your URL:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost/~myuser/mytest/public',
```

If your app is for development purposes, then you'll need to reverse the above, provided that the app will be running from the root of the public folder when it goes live.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Am I crazy or is there absolutely nothing about this in the Laravel docs?

Comment: You're welcome. So far as I know, there isn't. Many developers will argue that this is common knowledge - but I disagree. Many of those who are interested in Laravel are also newbies, which is what makes Laravel so great. I do think they should add it to the docs.